# Multiple parameters packages in variadic Template C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am studing variadic template and i was wondering if i could do something like this: I would to call an arbitrary number of functions (of arbitrary return type) with an arbitrary number and type of parameters with a single call. The code i would able to use is like:

```
call(f1,f2,f3, 2.2,3);
call(f4,f5, 2.2, "Hello", 'a');
```

Obviuosly if function passed can accept the argument passed.
I wrote a version that works with a fixed number of parameters to be passed to functions:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void fcall(const T& t1, const T& t2, U&& u){
    u(t1, t2);
}

template<typename... F, typename T, typename U>
void fcall(const T& t1, const T& t2, U&& u, F&&... f){
    u(t1, t2);
    fcall(t1, t2, f...);
}
```

Even if I don't like to pass parameters before functions, it works.

This is what I wrote and that doesn't work:

```
template<typename P, typename U>
void fcall2(U&& f, const P& param){
f(param);
}

template<typename... P, typename... F, typename U>
void fcall2(U&& f, F&&... func, const P&... param){
f(param...);
fcall2(func..., param...);
}
```

I know it's useless, it's only a curiosity.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one pack like that.

In theory you could find the unique split point in the pack that lets the elements before all be called with the elements after using stupidly complex template metaprogramming.

Easier would be to write:

```
template<class...Fs>
auto call_all(Fs...fs){
  return [&](auto&&...args){
    (void(fs(args...)),...);
  };
}
```

(C++17).

Used like:

```
call_all(f1,f2,f3)(3.13, "hello");
```